# How would I correctly run an ANOVA with only one factor as well as a blocked design?

Tags: r, anova

I hope this question isn't too simple. I searched on stack overflow and couldn't find an answer and google gave me mixed results. It's been a while since I've done statistics and I'm worried I'm doing something wrong.

Here is the head of my data to give an idea of what it looks like:

```
Rate Rep Yield
4   1          300.0762
3   1          351.0482
2   1          396.0897
1   1          384.9683
2   2          362.0108
3   2          392.1081
```

Pretty straightforward dataset. I know the basic setup of an anova would be as follows:

```
lm <-lm(Yield~ Rate, data=rawData)
anova(lm)
```

However, I'm not sure what the correct way to add my block (rep) in. Would it just be this?

```
lm <-lm(Yield~ Rate + Rep, data=rawData)
anova(lm)
```

Or something else? Thanks very much for any help and please let me know if I'm breaking any rules here.

Comment: Is your question more about the statistics side of setting up your model, or the code side? If it's the stats, it should be on [stats.se] instead. If it's the code, maybe fill in some detail on where exactly you're confused

Comment: What you propose is perfectly sensical if it is a randomized block design, please see here (http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/analysis-variance/randomized-block-design) to check whether it matches that experimental design